# Flutter - How to compress image to display thumbnail?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am making a flutter app which loads about 700+ image from Cloud Storage through Firebase. Though, I am using pagination, the app still crashes sometimes on low end devices(does not crash on emulator). I have already compressed all my images, still sometimes it crashes. Is there a way to compress images when we load them from firestore to display only low quality thumbnails. It's a wallpaper app. So what I want to do is, display low quality images when loading all of them to reduce work load on the device and then use the original quality when setting them as wallpaper.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I assume you're loading the images from Cloud Storage through Firebase, and not from Firestore itself. Firestore is a document database, while Cloud Storage is used for storing files. While both are part of Firebase, it's best not to confuse them.*

There is no built-in functionality to generate thumbnails in Firebase or Cloud Storage. But there is an [extension to resize images](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images) that you can enable, and that will then generate a thumbnail (or your specification) when new images are uploaded.